# MQTT broker communication to MQTT Client

Tags: mqtt, cumulocity

I already have a `cumulocity` client that communicates with the `cumulocity` broker through MQTT.

What should I do in order to send data back from MQTT broken in `cumulocity` to `mqtt` client? (Say the client sends some data and I want the confirmation that the data was sent successfully)

For some reason couldn't find any info on this on the `cumulocity` docs the only for client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get confirmation from the server of getting your data you should use the normal MQTT QoS. http://cumulocity.com/guides/mqtt/implementation/

If you want to send data in general from the platform to your device client operations is what you are looking for. This is currently the only data you can subscribe to on Cumulocity MQTT.
http://cumulocity.com/guides/concepts/domain-model/#operations

You can check the python example. It contains the subscription part
http://cumulocity.com/guides/mqtt/hello-mqtt-python/

Answer (score 0):

You should connect to the broker with **Qos 1** or above. This will guarantee that the data has reached the broker **at least once**. The client will be receiving the **PUBACK** message once this happens. If the connectivity is lost then the client is supposed to re-send the PUBLISH message with Duplicate flag set. So the cient should stop publishing when a **PUBACK** is received.

For more information about Qos, refer this link
[HiveMQ/blog/mqtt-essentials/QualityOfService](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-6-mqtt-quality-of-service-levels)